How to hide certain network calls from network traffic log
During debugging there are pages with a ton of calls to analytics and other useless stuff, is there some way to permanently filter them from the log in network traffic? Even if I have to add urls for each domain, eg. google, stripe, linkedin.
PS, not sure if this should go in superuser but seemed a bit more technical.
